# Get Object based on Key Value in Angular ui-router state params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve an object in Firebase based on one of he objects key values in ui-router $stateParams. Example:

Firebase structure:

```
"businesses" : {
    "-KP_XEBaYA8OlN6WOusx" : {
      "category" : "restaurant",
      "link" : "urlfriendly",
      "name" : "Some Restaurant"
    },
```

The link for this page would look like so:

```
website.com/food/restaurants/urlfriendly
```

In my app.js:

```
.state('food.restaurants.item',{
            url: '/:item',
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
                return 'pages/business.html'
            },
            controller: function($scope, $firebaseArray $stateParams){
                var sref = firebase.database().ref().child("businesses");
                $scope.restarants = $firebaseArray(sref); 
                var matches = $scope.restaurants.filter(function(val, index, array){
                    return val.link === $stateParams.item;
                });
                $scope.finalItem = matches[0];
            }
        })
```

The end result would be `$scope.finalItem` loaded with one of the objects so I could do something like:

```
<h2>{{finalItem.name}}</h2>
```

Comment: Computed access: `object[key]`. Try it.

Comment: @SomePerson It's been awhile from the initial question but could you give what you mentioned as an example? I am having difficulty understanding...I am not well versed in terminology.